# Server-side data validation in Meteor

Tags: javascript, validation, meteor, backend

I have a form and a submit function in my **client** file:

```
function submitme () {
    var message = $('#daform').serializeJSON();
    message.owner = Meteor.user().username;
    if(!message.description || !message.location.lat || !message.location.lng || !message.mysex || !message.yoursex) {
      return;          
      }
      else
      {
          lists.insert(message);
          console.log("Submitted!");
          $('#daform')[0].reset();
      }
}
```

That works pretty well although - it's **CLIENT** side validation => not secure.

How do I implement a "back-up" validation check in my server file?  ( + bonus question : how do I set a timer so that once you've submitted you need to wait X seconds before you re-submit? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use http://docs.meteor.com/#deny (You can use allow but it might be easier to put validation stuff in a seperate deny) as deny will override allow in the event it shouldn't be inserted:

It works just as a backup method on the server just before its inserted.

With your message collection

**Server Js**

```
message.deny({
    insert: function (userId, doc) {
        return (!doc.description || !doc.location.lat || !doc.location.lng || !doc.mysex || !doc.yoursex);
    },
    update: function (userId, docs, fields, modifier) {
        return (!doc.description || !doc.location.lat || !doc.location.lng || !doc.mysex || !doc.yoursex);
    }
);
```

**Note**: Returning false from deny means not to deny. To deny the update, you must return true.

Comment: thanks! would that mean: `lists.deny({
  update: function () {
    return false;
  }
});` that all updates are disabled? (doesnt work :/)

Comment: to deny all updates you need to return `true` instead, `false` means you don't want to deny it. Which one doesn't work the one I posted?

Comment: ah yeah, true, sorry I mixed the deny/allow.. (no, mine, I try yours now but I m sure it will work)

Comment: FYI `collection.deny` **does not validate server-side writes**. But it does securely validate client-side writes, which satisfies the question but could be misleading. https://gist.github.com/colllin/adf4626cc3e38391e5f7

Comment: @colllin Both allow and deny rules are only impacted by stuff sent over the wire from the client. From the server you always get full access. This is mentioned in the docs, but perhaps I could have made it clearer

Comment: Yeah, definetly this is not the way to do validation on the server-side

Comment: @JulioMarins Yes, not in the context in which you are considering. If you see what this question asks it is about validating data sent from the client on the server side, which the allow and deny rules are perfect for.

Comment: @Akshat btw, do you know a good way to validate data on the server-side?

Comment: @JulioMarins Have you had a look at Meteor-schema: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema & Collection2: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2